# Problems reading variables that start with zero in RODBC package at R

Tags: r

Hi everybody I am having problems trying to read a excel file like this in R with RODBC package:

```
c1   c2   c3
A    123  08
B    12   09
C    111  07
D    111  08
```

The code I use to read the excel file with that structure is:

```
library(RODBC)
Base="R04.xlsx"
conexion=odbcConnectExcel2007(Base)
Data=sqlQuery(channel=conexion,"select * from [Hoja1$]",as.is=TRUE)
close(conexion)
```

But I get this in R:

```
c1   c2   c3
A    123  8
B    12   9
C    111  7
D    111  8
```

The fact is `c3` is a code and I need the zero in front. The same happens when I save the file and open in excel, zero has dissapeared. How I make this in R and RODBC package. It is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format your cells in column c3 as text rather than numbers. Select the cells, then right-click, "Format cells", select "Text", then OK. Then you may have to re-edit the cells to add the leading 0s back and re-save the file.

After that your R code works, I just tested it:

```
> sqlQuery(channel=conn,"select * from [Sheet1$]", as.is=TRUE)
  c1  c2 c3
1  A 123 08
2  B  12 09
3  C 111 07
4  D 111 08
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to force the column to be characters, rather than digits as the latter will be read into a numeric or integer type which are display without leading zeros.

You could change it after the fact:

```
R> sprintf("%02d", c(8,9,7,8))
[1] "08" "09" "07" "08"
R>
```

Comment: But I want to read direct from file your solution could change other numbers @DirkEddelbuettel